# How to detect many very dense long lines with opencv python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, houghlinesp, houghlines

I am trying to detect all the very long lines in an image, which also lie very close and dense to each other, as depicted in the attached image.

I tried `HoughLinesP` and `HoughLines` with simple lines of code of Python OpenCV, but I can not find a good solution.

Thanks.

[image]

I tried `HoughLinesP` and `HoughLines` with several lines of code of Python OpenCV.

I was expecting detected lines, but they don't really work for me, I found parts of the lines but not the whole lines.

Comment: Threshold, crop the first and last N columns. Look for the color transitions, every transition is a starting/ending point of a new line.

Comment: If the lines are too thick, you can average the number of transitions (two per line) or get the skeleton image after thresholding

Comment: the lines are not thick, actually, they are extremely thin, diameter around 50 μm

Comment: A similar approach as described above, can be to threshold, get contours and evaluate the line from each contour. Please let us know if you have any further issues. Please share what you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

solved.

get a column at beginning, find contours, get mid points of contours
get a column at end, find contours, get mid points of contours

connect each pair of points.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).